# CSS background upload to server

Tags: css

I have recently added a picture to my website background through CSS on dreamweaver. I have saved the css file and the image file to the server yet this still doesn't appear on my website. Where have I gone wrong?

The code I'm using is background-image: url(../images/Christmasback.png); and I have put this in the body. In dreamweaver view in browser it works fine

Folder structure is

```
Site root
- WWW
     - CSS
          - site.css
     - Images
          - Christmasback.png
     - index.html
```

CSS code is:

```
html,body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #333;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 16px;
    background-image: url(../images/Christmasback.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

and header as well:

```
#header {
    position: relative;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 908px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-image: url(../images/xmas-header.gif);
}
```

Comment: Any code? Any folder structure dump? Anything?

Comment: Where do you want us to look at? Do we have to guess your code and folder structure or will you just post it?

Comment: code I'm using is background-image: url(../images/Christmasback.png); and I have put this in the body. In dreamweaver view in browser it works fine

Comment: Yeah, that's not enough, you need to post your code and your folder structure in your question exactly how it is in your website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to refresh your cache to see the updated images.

In Windows/Linux Press Ctrl + F5 in your browser, on a mac press Cmd + R

You will want to look at Expiring Content for future reference when developing:

http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Under the Add an Expires or a Cache-Control Header title, it allows you to add an expiry date for images/css etc so the browser will get the latest version at specified times.

Comment: You're a star, That worked straight away!